# Fedora 31 Workstation for Ryzen 3900X - X570 - Radeon RX 5700XT

Tags: fedora

After multiple attempts I managed to get Fedora Workstation running via nightly builds. Since this is a workstation I'm actually uncomfortable continuing to work on what I'm assuming is a test system.

What is the best way to get a stable system? Do I just keep this install and disable the "Testing" repositories?

Do I wait for a new beta of Fedora 31 that actually works for the components in my system or is that frozen? (current beta isn't working)

Here's the exact hardware:

- Gigabyte X570 AORUS ELITE (Bios f5b)
- Samsung 970 PRO 1TB M.2
- G.Skill Ripjaws V F4-3600C19Q-64GVR
- AMD Ryzen 9 3900X
- CORSAIR AX Series AX850
- MSI Radeon RX 5700 XT MECH OC

Beta installer hangs after displaying:

```
[ OK ] Starting GNOME Display Manager...
       Starting Hold until boot process finished up...
[ OK ] Started GNOME Display Manager...
```

Ctrl+Alt+F2 is not working.

I tried to change the boot options but somehow my keyboard is not working. When I hit the f key the screen is displaying ffffffffffffff. I also cannot edit existing options due to a corrupt keyboard interaction.

According to u/poyepolomi on reddit r/Fedora I need to set nomodeset however due to none of my keyboard working (I tested 3 keyboard) I cannot add the boot options. (it feels like keyboard repeat is super high)

Keyboard issue fixed by disabling CSM (Compatibility Support Module) in BIOS

Comment: The output of `dmesg` would be good too.

Comment: Which bits of the hardware list don't work for you? Please don't make us have to keep guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So multiple problems occurred

- Gigabyte X570 AORUS ELITE: Keyboard issue fixed by disabling CSM (Compatibility Support Module) in BIOS
- Fedora 31 beta install fixed by adding boot option nomodeset after quiet